# Encoding and decoding Portuguese word in python in linux envrionment

Tags: python, linux, unicode

This is my function to encode and decode the Portuguese word:

```
def decoded_string(input_string):
    return input_string.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

This is the output in windows: Mario Exportação

But in Linux, it is showing this output: Mario ExportaÃ§Ã£o

Windows is my local machine and Linux is our server machine. I don't know why it's not working there and I even added RUN `apt-get install -y fonts-dejavu` in my docker container to support the Portuguese

Comment: I consider the question as providing insufficient details. What encoding does your input_string have and what do you intend by latin-1 encoding?

Comment: That encode-decode sequence is pretty nonsensical. Instead, [run Python in UTF-8 mode on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode) and fix things to work there, and everything should be okay on Linux too.

Comment: Also, installing fonts doesn't matter in the least here...

Comment: `input_string.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` This doesn't make much sense at all. Why are you doing this? Ny guess would be that your output on Linux is garbled because your server is set up to use the C locale or perhaps some Latin1 locale by default.

Comment: What is your input string? Give us some context. Make a [mcve]

Comment: This would only make sense if the original string was a UTF-8-mis-decoded-as-latin1, Unicode-escaped `str` in the first place.

Comment: let me explain what i am doing i signing a pdf digitally these two thing are happening during creating a csr file using openssl

f'openssl req -new -key {private_key} -out {csr_path} -subj "/C={country}/ST={state}/L={city}/O={organization}/OU={organizational_unit}/CN={username} <{email}>"'

this is the input i pass to CN- Mario Exportação

in windows environment its working but in linux server is not working

Mario Exporta\C3\83\C2\A7\C3\83\C2\A3o - linux server
Mario Exporta\C3\A7\C3\A3o - windows

Comment: @HariHaran Explain it by **editing the question** with a clear example.  Make a [mcve] (<- *read the link*)

Comment: @HariHaran, I expect the input is in WIndows-1252 on Windows, and UTF-8 on Linux, the odd encode/decode sequences might work on Windows, but you code is using different encodings on different operating systems and you attempts to get around problems on Windows is corrupting data on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are expecting on sub process in python. Actually you need add `-utf8` flag at the end of the cmd... This works only on Linux environment, whereas in windows it will work fine without the flag

openssl req -new -key /app/cert/sign.key -out /app/temp/cert-csr.pem -subj "/C=IN/ST=Coimbatore /L=India/O=Tech /OU=Técnico/CN=Mãnoj Kumar " -utf8

Comment: although this is accepted and upvoted, it does not seem to make sense in this case at all.